# How do you get the "Bi-Winning" Achievement?

Tags: achievements, dirt-showdown

The achievement says:

> **[Bi-Winning](http://astats.astats.nl//astats/Steam_Achievement_Info.php?AchievementID=2&AppID=201700)**
>   Complete a Splitscreen event

Do you have to play with 2 players to get this achievement or is this a game mode?

If you have to play with 2 players, is there any way to "fake" this if you don't have any gaming related real life friends and only 1 controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply turn on a second controller and complete the race with one of the two, the achievement will be unlocked. There's nothing special about it, just a split-screen event needs to be completed. If you were to be playing the Steam version, theoretically you could do it all on one keyboard if you don't have ghosting problems, otherwise a keyboard and gamepad or wheel combination would work.

Comment: I noticed the mis-match but just assumed the body was correct and not the title; updated with new answer.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted + accepted. I need to test about only having 1 controller though. If I can do it with controller + keyboard or so.

Comment: The controller and keyboard combo should definitely work, as that's effectively how split-screen is meant to be played on PC. By design having two players on a single keyboard would be bad as most keyboards would run into ghosting issues, and not allowing the keyboard would be non-sensical. As you're playing by yourself however, you should be able to configure just a couple of basic controls for player 2 on the keyboard and do it all without even having to plug the controller in. Hopefully that clears things up!